# all the text on the pdf is rendering as squares/blocks □

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, openhtmltopdf

**Why is my output being generated with just squares?**

I'm attempting to convert html to a pdf, and I'm getting a weird output, where all the characters are squares, as in the following:

[image]

My function is below:

```
   public static class ConstructPDFHttpTriggered
    {
        [FunctionName("ConstructPDFHttpTriggered")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Processing PDF Request");

            string dataDetails = string.Empty;
            bool isError = false;

            try
            {
                string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                            .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                            .Value;

                if (name == null)
                {
                    // Get request body
                    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                    name = data?.name;
                }

                //Constrcut PDF object
                var pdf = Pdf

                    .From(name)
                    .WithObjectSetting("web.printMediaType", "true")
                    .Content();

                log.Info($"PDF Generated. Length={pdf.Length}");

                //Convert PDF stream to base64 string
                dataDetails = Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isError = true;
                dataDetails = ex.Message;
            }

            return isError
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dataDetails)
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataDetails);
        }
    }
```

**Why is my output being generated with just squares? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: maybe the font does not exist in PDF?

Comment: interesting, how do i go about exploring that?

Comment: check your pdf generator, maybe use a regular font to see whether it renders correctly.

Comment: well as you can see i'm not specifying the font

Comment: the content is html which may use special font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that we were not able to run this on the [consumption plan](http://twocents.nl/?p=2078). The [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) library uses fonts, which requires an OS to be present within that environment. After switching the function to an [App Sevice plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans), this issue was simply resolved.